# Bootstrap CSS grid not aligning

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

**New to Bootstrap and using version 5-2-0**

In my layout I wanted to have the image of the cat take up one side and then have the content and form on the other size (content first then form underneath) but I can't get it to work.

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="g-col-6 g-start-1">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt="kitty kitty">
  </div>
  <div class="g-col-6 g-start-6">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni natus reiciendis corrupti quasi sit, ipsam officia doloribus totam fuga pariatur aliquid! Molestias et sapiente iusto, perspiciatis similique rem ipsum dolores?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="g-col-6 g-start-6">form</div>
</div>
```

**Codepen**:
https://codepen.io/emmabbb/pen/ExRmgZE

Answer (score 0):

In you're code, you were missing the stylesheet for https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/assets/css/docs.css.

Also you need to start from `g-start-7` (instead of g-start-6) as 1-6 is for the first column and 7-12 is for the second columns

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">   

    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="grid">
  <div class="g-col-6">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt="kitty kitty">
  </div>
  <div class="g-col-6 g-start-7">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni natus reiciendis corrupti quasi sit, ipsam officia doloribus totam fuga pariatur aliquid! Molestias et sapiente iusto, perspiciatis similique rem ipsum dolores?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="g-col-6 g-start-7">form</div>
</div>
```

See more details here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/css-grid/#how-it-works

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But if I wanted to use the new CSS grid in Bootstrap is there no way?

Comment: @EmmaStone sorry I misread the question. Please see the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

This should do.

**Code:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt="kitty kitty">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni natus reiciendis corrupti quasi sit, ipsam officia doloribus totam fuga pariatur aliquid! Molestias et sapiente iusto, perspiciatis similique rem ipsum dolores?</p>
    <div>form</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 5.2 * need to add !important in g-start classes.

```
.g-start-2 { grid-column-start: 2 !important; }
```